# Get Focus at first control in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

my layout like :

[image]

i want focus at Company Name Texfield  when i press TAB button at first time , but right now i get focus at Add Button how can i manage it ?

i try code like

```
    ChangeFocus(mTextFieldCompanyName, mTextAreaAboutUs);
    ChangeFocus(mTextAreaAboutUs, mTextAreaContactUs);
    ChangeFocus(mTextAreaContactUs, mButtonVideo);
    ChangeFocus(mButtonVideo, mButtonImage);
    ChangeFocus(mButtonImage, mButtonSave);
    public void ChangeFocus(Control mControlFrom,final Control mControlTo)
    {

   mControlFrom.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

         @Override
         public void handle(KeyEvent event)
         {
             if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB)
             {
                System.out.println("TAB pressed");
                mControlTo.requestFocus();
                event.consume(); // do nothing
         }
       }
     });

     }
```

Answer (score 7):

Try wrapping your mTextFieldCompanyName inside `Platform.runLater()`

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mTextFieldCompanyName.requestFocus();  
    }   
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: @UnKnown It is not possible to achieve the above in FXML

Comment: any other way to focus to textField that is added with FXML?